# Add download file feature to ubercart products using rules

Tags: rules, ubercart

I am using drupal 7 and ubercart along with ubercart file download module.

Is there any way to add download file feature to ubercart products using rules, based on some attribute conditions I have to add the file with a ubercart product, so I prefer to use rules for this.
Now I do not understand is there any way to add files with particular product using rules...help will be greatly appreciated...